# Discrete space $(X, \tau)$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ iff $X$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}$ have the Euclidean topology (i.e., with Euclidean distance), and let $(X, \tau)$ be a discrete topological space.

Prove that $(X, \tau)$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ iff $X$ is countable.

Let $X$ be countable.  If $|X|$$=n$,  then the subspace $A=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ with the induced Euclidean topology is homeomorphic to $(X, \tau)$.  If X is  countably infinite, then the subspace $\mathbb{N} $ is homeomophic to $(X, \tau)$.

Now how we can prove the other direction, i.e., if $(X, \tau)$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, then $X$ is countable?

Comment: As it's written right now the question is not understandable (for me), could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: if  $B \subset \mathbb{R} $ with  Euclidean distance be homeomorphic  with (X,T) that T is discrete topology then prove X is countable .

Comment: Are you asking "Prove that every discrete subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable"?

Comment: I think he means: prove that there is a subspace $A$ of $\mathbb R$ such that a subspace of $A$  is discrete if and only if it is countable.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti. yes.

Comment: why can't you just set $A=\mathbb{Z}$ then? Or even $A=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Prove the contrapositive: show that if $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is uncountable, then the relative topology on $A$ is *not* discrete. One way to do this is to let $\mathscr{B}$ be a countable base for the topology of $\Bbb R$, and let

$$\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:B\cap A\text{ is countable}\}\;.$$

- Show that $A\cap\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0$ is countable.

Let $A_0=A\setminus\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0$.

- Show that $A\ne\varnothing$, and that each $x\in A_0$ is a limit point of $A$. Conclude that $A$ is not discrete in its relative topology.